# Handling different column types in different databases

Tags: java, oracle, postgresql, jdbc, database-design

I have an existing database which contains a table with primary key column of type int and I’m planning to create a new database which will hold more data in this table with primary key column of type bigint.

Is it possible for my Java application to access either database and read the table regardless of if the column is int or bigint?

These are unique databases with totally separate data in them but the same schema.

I also currently work with PostgreSQL and Oracle and would want to ensure anything I do works with them both.

Comment: build a data model, understand the data you'll be working with, then look for ANSI defined data types supported by all of your vendors, but then also be aware of how things like NULL dates are treated differently btwn say oracle and psql - so your app code may differe slightly on logic side

Comment: The difference between int and bigint should be trivial.

Comment: What @thatjeffsmith said.  If you want to access multiple databases, your code has to accommodate the smallest common field types.  *Is it possible for my Java application to access either database and read the table regardless of if the column is int or bigint?* Sure.  You read both field types into a long.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply provide that field type as **`Long`** in your java class.

Automatically according to int or **`bigint`**, it will map with that **`Long`** field. As Long have 8 bytes size, it will able to stores whole numbers from **`-9,223,372,036,854,775,808 to 9,223,372,036,854,775,807.`**

For size of primitives you can refer [**`this`**](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_data_types.asp).

So no need to worry.

Answer (score 1):

- If oracle number size is less than 10 use java int datatype.
- If oracle number size is less than 20 use java long datatype.
- Otherwise use java BigInteger datatype.